# Restrict the @fileupload helper to image only

Tags: html, razor, html-helper, webmatrix

Is there a way to add a line to this to "force" image only?

```
    @FileUpload.GetHtml(
        initialNumberOfFiles:4,
        allowMoreFilesToBeAdded:false,
        includeFormTag:true,
        ???Image only kind of line????
        uploadText:"Send")
```

If not, is there a way in the function like

```
if(IsPost && Validation.IsValid()){
      var uploadedFile1 = Request.Files[0];
      var uploadedFile2 = Request.Files[1];
      if(Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile1.FileName) != String.Empty){
      var fileName1 = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile1.FileName);
      var fileSavePath1 = Server.MapPath("/path/UploadedFiles/" + DateP + fileName1);
          uploadedFile1.SaveAs(fileSavePath1);
      image1 = "/path/UploadedFiles/" + DateP + fileName1;
      }
      if(Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile2.FileName) != String.Empty){
      var fileName2 = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile2.FileName);
      var fileSavePath2 = Server.MapPath("/path/UploadedFiles/" + DateP + fileName2);
          uploadedFile2.SaveAs(fileSavePath2);
      image2 = "/path/UploadedFiles/" + DateP + fileName2;  
      }
      ???Like if filename extension is different than jpg or gif, or bmp then "hell no, i'm not uploading this" kind of function????
```

And I know about the accept attribute into the 
      `<input type="file" />`
but adding it to this code doesn't seems that simple...

Thank you

Comment: Assuming that helper generates an `<input type="file" />` element, you're after the [accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-accept) attribute.

Comment: Yes If I was using exactly the <input type="file" /> it would have been easy. But I don't know how to add the accept attribute into @FileUpload.GetHtml() helper... =/... I've been searching a lot and I begin to think it's not possible that's why I ask for option "B" with the function

Comment: That helper doesn't supply that option. You can either tweak it with JavaScript after it's been rendered, or use the [source code](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/ASP.NET-Mvc-3/blob/master/webpages/src/Microsoft.Web.Helpers/FileUpload.cs) to build a derivative that includes an "allowed types" argument.

Comment: You seem to have the answer here... I don't know we could to that... I'll go try to learn a bit about this. Thank you...

btw Damn people are quick to downvote something they couldn't even be able to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've done everything by modifying the code like this

```
 var filename1b = Path.GetExtension(uploadedFile1.FileName);
 if (filename1b == ".jpg" || filename1b == ".JPG" || filename1b == ".gif" || filename1b == ".GIF" || filename1b == ".bmp" || filename1b == ".BMP" || filename1b == ".png" || filename1b == ".PNG")
```

It seems to work... I should have took the opportunity to learn more about the modification of the helper, but I think I'm missing to much elements... Sorry Tieson T.

Answer (score 1):

The [required changes](https://gist.github.com/tiesont/70ea02d85acb7d551c41) aren't all that difficult:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Internal.Web.Utils;
using Microsoft.Web.Helpers.Resources;

namespace YourNamespaceHere
{
    // Extended to include accept attribute
    // Original: https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/ASP.NET-Mvc-3/blob/master/webpages/src/Microsoft.Web.Helpers/FileUpload.cs
    public static class FileUploadEx
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates HTML for multiple file upload.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">The value assigned to the name attribute of the file upload input elements.</param>
        /// <param name="initialNumberOfFiles">Initial number of file upload fields to display.</param>
        /// <param name="allowMoreFilesToBeAdded">If true, allows more file upload fields to be added.</param>
        /// <param name="includeFormTag">If true, result includes form tag around all file input tags and submit button. 
        /// If false, user needs to specify their own form tag around call to GetHtml with their own submit button.</param>
        /// <param name="addText">Text to display on a link that allows more file upload fields can be added.</param>
        /// <param name="uploadText">Text to display on the submit button.</param>
        /// <param name="allowedTypes">Comma-separated string for the allowed MIME types for the input element.</param>
        public static HtmlString GetHtml(
            string name = null,
            int initialNumberOfFiles = 1,
            bool allowMoreFilesToBeAdded = true,
            bool includeFormTag = true,
            string addText = null,
            string uploadText = null,
            string allowedTypes = null)
        {

            HttpContextBase httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
            FileUploadImplementation fileUpload = new FileUploadImplementation(httpContext);
            return fileUpload.GetHtml(name: name, initialNumberOfFiles: initialNumberOfFiles, allowMoreFilesToBeAdded: allowMoreFilesToBeAdded, includeFormTag: includeFormTag,
                addText: addText, uploadText: uploadText, allowedTypes: allowedTypes);
        }
    }

    internal class FileUploadImplementation
    {
        private static readonly object _countKey = new object();
        private static readonly object _scriptAlreadyRendered = new object();

        private readonly HttpContextBase _httpContext;

        public FileUploadImplementation(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            _httpContext = httpContext;
        }

        private int RenderCount
        {
            get
            {
                int? count = _httpContext.Items[_countKey] as int?;
                if (!count.HasValue)
                {
                    count = 0;
                }
                return count.Value;
            }
            set
            {
                _httpContext.Items[_countKey] = value;
            }
        }

        private bool ScriptAlreadyRendered
        {
            get
            {
                bool? rendered = _httpContext.Items[_scriptAlreadyRendered] as bool?;
                return rendered.HasValue && rendered.Value;
            }
            set
            {
                _httpContext.Items[_scriptAlreadyRendered] = value;
            }
        }

        public HtmlString GetHtml(
            string name,
            int initialNumberOfFiles,
            bool allowMoreFilesToBeAdded,
            bool includeFormTag,
            string addText,
            string uploadText,
            string allowedTypes)
        {

            if (initialNumberOfFiles < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                    "initialNumberOfFiles",
                    String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, CommonResources.Argument_Must_Be_GreaterThanOrEqualTo, "0"));
            }

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(addText))
            {
                addText = HelpersToolkitResources.FileUpload_AddMore;
            }
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(uploadText))
            {
                uploadText = HelpersToolkitResources.FileUpload_Upload;
            }
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            {
                name = "fileUpload";
            }


            TagBuilder formTag = null;
            if (includeFormTag)
            {
                // <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                formTag = new TagBuilder("form");
                formTag.MergeAttribute("method", "post");
                formTag.MergeAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
                formTag.MergeAttribute("action", "");
            }

            // <div id="file-upload-all-files">
            TagBuilder outerDivTag = new TagBuilder("div");
            outerDivTag.MergeAttribute("id", "file-upload-" + RenderCount);
            outerDivTag.MergeAttribute("class", "file-upload");

            // <div><input type="file" name="fileUpload"/></div>                
            TagBuilder fileInputTag = new TagBuilder("input");
            fileInputTag.MergeAttribute("type", "file");
            fileInputTag.MergeAttribute("name", "fileUpload");

            // ****************************************************************
            // Added accept attribute
            // *
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(allowedTypes))
            {
                fileInputTag.MergeAttribute("accept", allowedTypes);
            }
            // *
            // ****************************************************************

            TagBuilder innerDivTag = new TagBuilder("div");
            innerDivTag.InnerHtml = fileInputTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);

            outerDivTag.InnerHtml = String.Join(String.Empty, Enumerable.Repeat(innerDivTag.ToString(), initialNumberOfFiles));

            TagBuilder aTag = null;
            if (allowMoreFilesToBeAdded)
            {
                // <a href="#" onclick="FileUploadHelper.addInputElement(1, "foo"); return false;" >Add more!</a>
                aTag = new TagBuilder("a");
                aTag.MergeAttribute("href", "#");
                aTag.MergeAttribute("onclick",
                        String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                            "FileUploadHelper.addInputElement({0}, {1}); return false;",
                            RenderCount, HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(name, addDoubleQuotes: true)));
                aTag.SetInnerText(addText);
            }

            // <input value="Upload" type="submit"/>
            TagBuilder submitInputTag = null;
            if (includeFormTag)
            {
                submitInputTag = new TagBuilder("input");
                submitInputTag.MergeAttribute("type", "submit");
                submitInputTag.MergeAttribute("value", uploadText);
            }

            StringBuilder finalHtml = new StringBuilder();
            if (allowMoreFilesToBeAdded && !ScriptAlreadyRendered)
            {
                finalHtml.Append(_UploadScript);
                ScriptAlreadyRendered = true;
            }

            if (includeFormTag)
            {
                StringBuilder formTagContent = new StringBuilder();
                ComposeFileUploadTags(formTagContent, outerDivTag, aTag, submitInputTag);
                formTag.InnerHtml = formTagContent.ToString();
                finalHtml.Append(formTag.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                ComposeFileUploadTags(finalHtml, outerDivTag, aTag, submitInputTag);
            }

            RenderCount++;
            return new HtmlString(finalHtml.ToString());
        }

        private static void ComposeFileUploadTags(StringBuilder sb, TagBuilder outerDivTag, TagBuilder aTag, TagBuilder submitTag)
        {
            sb.Append(outerDivTag.ToString());

            if ((aTag != null) || (submitTag != null))
            {

                TagBuilder divTag = new TagBuilder("div");
                divTag.MergeAttribute("class", "file-upload-buttons");

                StringBuilder innerHtml = new StringBuilder();
                if (aTag != null)
                {
                    innerHtml.Append(aTag.ToString());
                }

                if (submitTag != null)
                {
                    innerHtml.Append(submitTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
                }

                divTag.InnerHtml = innerHtml.ToString();
                sb.Append(divTag.ToString());
            }
        }

        private const string _UploadScript =
"<script type=\"text/javascript\">" +
    "if (!window[\"FileUploadHelper\"]) window[\"FileUploadHelper\"] = {}; " +
    "FileUploadHelper.addInputElement = function(index, name) { " +
        "var inputElem = document.createElement(\"input\"); " +
        "inputElem.type = \"file\"; " +
        "inputElem.name = name; " +
        "var divElem = document.createElement(\"div\"); " +
        "divElem.appendChild(inputElem.cloneNode(false)); " + //Appending the created node creates an editable text field in IE8.
        "var inputs = document.getElementById(\"file-upload-\" + index); " +
        "inputs.appendChild(divElem); " +
"} </script>";
    }
}
```

The problem is that the original version relies on some assemblies that aren't normally referenced in a web project, so you'll need to track these down:

- Microsoft.Internal.Web.Utils
- Microsoft.Web.Helpers.Resources

If you'd prefer a client-side solution, jQuery can be used to add the relevant attribute:

```
$('input[name="fileUpload"]').attr({ 'accept', 'image/*' });
```

I don't know how either of the above changes affects the JavaScript powering the helper, so caveat emptor.

Comment: I know everything is here... I'm just not good enough to understand it well... =( I've always tryed to avoid using this because I'm not confortable. But it seems I have to learn it now... I'm using Webmatrix and I don't even know where to put the file and all. Thank you very much I'll try to understand it

Comment: But just a little question... Where do you put the allowed file type in your code? Or is it some line that the html helper will be able to take because of this derivative

Comment: It's a static class (as was the original), so it can go anywhere. I'd recommend either simply using a one-off class (with the name above), or adding it to combined file (like HtmlHelperExtensions.cs) if you're going to add more. The code above adds the attribute around line 137, plus the constructor has an additional parameter.